# Creating and writingf content to a file in XSL coding

Tags: xml, file, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi I just want to write below xml in to a file called test.xml through xsl

```
<Number>
<num>1</num>
<num>2</num>
</Number>
```

This is the output of the xsl and i wanted to store it on a test.xml file in my local machine.Please let me know how can i achieve this in XSL.I don't know file concepts in XSL,Is XSL is capable of doing this?..Please help

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? How do you run transforms (through a command prompt, or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below xsl helps,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <Number><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <num>1</num><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <num>2</num><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </Number>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested this myself. It should work.